# Formatação de data para salvar no Banco

Tags: php, html, mysql

Como fazer a Formatação de data no php, receber data padrão (d-m-Y) e salvar no Banco (Y-m-d).

Esta é a linha de código utilizada dentro do `input` (Y-m_d)

```
value="<?php $date = new DateTime(''); $date->add(new DateInterval('P0D')); echo $date->format('Y-m-d'); ?>
">
```

Comment: Alguns links que poderão ajudar: [Manipulando datas com PHP](https://www.devmedia.com.br/manipulando-datas-com-php/32966), [date](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há mais de uma maneira de se fazer o que você está querendo, caso queira manter o value do input com trechos de código, você poderia fazer o seguinte:

No seu input, crie uma propriedade *name* : `<input name="data">`

No script onde você trata os dados vindos do formulário você pode pegar os dados via `$_POST['data']` ou `$_GET['data']` dependendo do método escolhido para o envio do formulário.

Neste momento, acredito que o usuário inputou a data no formato d-m-Y, certo? Ok... Você fará algo desse gênero para converter para Y-m-d:

`$data = new DateTime($_POST['data']);`

`$dataFormatada = $data->format('Y-m-d')`;

Lembrando que daí pra frente você pode trabalhar normalmente colocando intervalos ou o que mais precisar e passando a responsabilidade de formatar a data para o script que trata o formulário após envio, você limpa um pouco mais a sua view e ajuda na legibilidade e manutenção posteriormente.